# Convert dictionary to pandas df with values being lists of numbers while keeping list format

Tags: python, pandas

Have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
opt = {
            red: [28, 30, 32],
            blue: [30],
            green: [28, 32, 34, 38]
        }
```

And I'm looking to convert it to a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
| size     | color                        |
| -------- | --------------               |
| sml      | [red, blue, green]           |
| med      | [red]                        |
| lrg      | [red, blue, green, orange]   |
```

Any way to do that easily?

Comment: Hi and welcome, where does the information size come from? (when is it sml, med, lrg)? and how do you get orange as a value?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'color':[x for x in opt], 'rgb':[ opt[x] for x in opt] } )
```